# jquery .map() checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    alert($("#chk_option").val());
    $("#chk_option").val(this.value);
  }).get();
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<div>

  <center>
    <form id="form_tarif" class="form-horizontal" style="padding-top:57px;" action="pricesinput" method="POST">

      <input type="hidden" id="chk_option" name="chk_option">

      <input type="hidden" id="chk_option_remove" name="chk_option_remove">

      <c:forEach items="${option_tarif_list}" var="option_tarif" varStatus="loop">
        <div class="checkbox1">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tarif_inclue[]" value="${option_tarif.id}" class="checkboxchk" id="option_tarif_chk_${option_tarif.id}">${option_tarif.libelle}
          </label>
        </div>
      </c:forEach
   </form>
 </center>

</div>
```

I need the id `chk_option` for future use. How can i make the array of selected checkbox values included in that id.

JAVA code

I need the id as shown below

```
Integer trimmedOptionSplit = 0;
String optionChkStr = request.getParameter("chk_option");
String[] optionSplitStrs = optionChkStr.split(",");
```

Comment: what do you mean by included in that id??

Comment: As i said, i need the id for future use with all the values inside it. I will need to use it in my JAVA code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the checked checkboxes values in Comma separated format by using:

```
var checkedelemids = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

and then you can set the value to hidden input using:

```
$('#chk_option').val(checkedelemids);
```

Comment: if i make an alert; it doesnt seem to work alert($('#chk_option').val(checkOption));

Comment: can you share the fiddle??

Comment: Ok. this is the thing. You need to add rendered html and no server side code in fiddle.

Comment: unfortunately the checkbox is in a cforeach loop, but atleast the alert should have work ya :/

Comment: ok thank you very much @Milind Anantwar. Your answer was really helpful

Comment: glad it helps fadil :)